# Unrecognized option when nice used through ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, tar, nice

How to use `nice` on remote host via `ssh`?

I want to decrease priority for long interactive process, executed on remote host:

```
ssh server1 nice -n tar --update --preserve-permissions --file /opt/share/content/mirror/.tar --directory /opt/share/content/version/0 .
```

Error message:

> nice: unrecognized option '--update'
>
> Try 'nice --help' for more information.
>
> Connection to server1 closed.

`ssh -t`, short versions of parameters and any combination of quotes for `ssh` or `nice` parameters changes nothing.

`ssh server1 'echo $SHELL'` prints `/bin/bash`, if matters much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nice -n` needs a number, you have `tar`. This confuses the parser, I think.

Try:

```
ssh server1 nice -n 10 tar --update ...
```

or

```
ssh server1 nice tar --update ...
```

Comment: So, using with default parameters is not `nice -n *cmd*`, but `nice *cmd*`. Nice. `man nice` is not clear.